# Django Deploy ElasticBeanstalk StaticFiles(JS/CSS) not loading

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Styles Are Not Loading:

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'templates/static']

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

error eb logs:

```
Apr 26 06:11:06 ip-172-31-46-75 web: Not Found: /static/assets/bootstrap/css/animate.css
Apr 26 06:11:06 ip-172-31-46-75 web: Not Found: /static/assets/bootstrap/css/flex-slider.min.css
Apr 26 06:11:06 ip-172-31-46-75 web: Not Found: /static/assets/bootstrap/css/slicknav.min.css
Apr 26 06:11:06 ip-172-31-46-75 web: Not Found: /static/assets/custom/css/style.css

ETC..........
```

I also did in my env

> python manage.py collectstatic

and

> eb deploy

, it still didnt load my css/js(html is perfectly loading)

my .ebextensions:

```
option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
        WSGIPath: store.wsgi:application
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72027216/12942284 Hope this answer will fix your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a

> ststic-files.config

File and specify
the directories

```
option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
        /static: static
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
```