# AWS ElasticBeanstalk how to upload staticfiles with django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried uploading staticfiles:

aws:elasticbeanstalk:enviroment:proxy:staticfiles:
/static: /static

got this error in

```
2022-04-27 03:34:07    ERROR   "option_settings" in one of the configuration files failed validation. More details to follow.
2022-04-27 03:34:07    ERROR   Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:enviroment:proxy:staticfiles', OptionName: '/static'): Unknown configuration setting.
2022-04-27 03:34:07    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.

ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

I also tried only doing

> python manage.py collectstatic

and it did not work

I tried my settings.py in this way:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
```

and this way(current way im utilizing):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'templates/static']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following configuration which worked for me.

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
```

Run `python manage.py collect static`

Go to your root urls.py and add

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve 

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}), 
]
```

you can refer [Github](https://github.com/cyborg7898/poll-app)